# Spock label combinations

Tags: groovy, spock

[There](https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example/blob/master/src/test/groovy/DataDrivenSpec.groovy) | [are](https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example/blob/master/src/test/groovy/StackSpec.groovy) | [so many](http://thejavatar.com/testing-with-spock/) | [Spock](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/using-spock-to-test-groovy-and-java-applications/) | [spec](https://dzone.com/articles/introduction-spock) examples of how to use its labels, such as:

```
// when -> then label combo
def "test something"() {
    when:
    // blah

    then:
    // blah blah
}
```

Such label combinations as:

- `when` -> `then`
- `given` -> `when` -> `then`
- `expect`
- `given` -> `expect`

But nowhere can I find documentation on what the *legal*/meaningful combinations of these labels are. For instance, could I have:

```
def "do something"() {
    when:
    // blah

    expect:
    // blah
}
```

Could I? I do not know. What about:

```
def "do something else"() {
    when:
    // blah

    then:
    // blah

    expect:
    // blah

    where:
    // blah
}
```

Could I? Again, I do not know. But I wonder.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I am actually an author of one of the tutorials you have mentioned. I think the best to answer your question would be to really understand what particular labels are for. Maybe then it would be more obvious why certain combinations make sense and other do not. Please refer to original documentation http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/spock_primer.html. It explains really well all labels and their purpose. Also it comes with this diagram:

[image: Spock labels]

Which I hope should already tell you a lot. So for instance having both **when** and **expect** labels makes not much sense. The **expect** label was designed to substitute both **when** and **then**. The reasoning behind it is well explained in the documentation:

> An expect block [...] is useful in situations where it is more natural to describe stimulus and expected response in a single expression.

Spock itself will not allow you to use this combination. If you try to execute following code.

```
def "test"() {
    when:
        println("test")

    expect:
        1==1
}
```

You will receive an error message like this.

> startup failed:
> /Users/wooki/IdeaProjects/mylibrary/src/test/groovy/ExampleTest.groovy:
> 13: 'expect' is not allowed here; instead, use one of: [and, then] @
> line 13, column 9.

To my surprise the second of your examples works. However I believe there is really not much gain of using **expect** here instead of **and** as I would normally do.

```
def "do something else"() {
    when:
    // stimulus

    then:
    // 1st verification

    and:
    // 2nd verification

    where:
    // parametrization
}
```

The only reason to have **expect** or **and** after **then** is to separate code responsible for verifying the result of executing the code inside **when** label. For instance to group verifications that are somehow related to each other, or even to separate single verifications but to have a possibility of giving them a description using strings that can be attached to labels in Spock.

```
def "do something else"() {
    when:
    // stimulus

    then: "1 is always 1"
       1 == 1

    and: "2 is always 2"
       2 == 2
}
```

Hence, since you are already stating that verification part of the test began (using **then** block) I would stick to **and** label for separating further code.

Regarding **where** label. It works sort of as a loop indicator. So whatever combinations of labels you use before you could always put at the end the **where** label. This one is not really a part of a single test run, it just enforces the test to be run a number of times.

As well it is possible to have something like this:

```
def "test"() {
    given:
        def value

    when:
        value = 1

    then:
        value == 1

    when:
        value = 2

    then:
        value == 2
}
```

Using the above, just make sure that your test is not "testing too much". Meaning that maybe a reason why you use two groups of when-then makes a perfect excuse for this test to be actually split into two separate tests.

I hope this answered at least some of your questions.

Comment: Thanks @wooki (+1) - if you could explain the `where` label a little bit more I think I should be all set!

Comment: Hi @smeeb, I will try to edit my response when I have more time. In the meantime you could have a look at tests I have created some time ago in Spock. There are plenty of parametrized tests over there (the ones with **where** label). Hopefully it will give you better insight of what they are capable of and how useful they can be.  [tests are available here](https://github.com/TheJavatarCom/mastercoder03/blob/master/src/test/groovy/com/thejavatar/mastercoder03/ApplicationTest.groovy)

Comment: Not that I would be a fan of the approach (at least not without proper documentation), but combining when/then and expect within one test could be useful to manipulate Stub/Mock scoping to override methods differently between then when/then & expect blocks.

Comment: It's not nearly complete, but I've started to document everything I've been learning about Spock. [Here are some examples of the where label](https://github.com/ScientificMethod/SpockExamples/blob/master/SpockExamples/src/test/Parameterizations.groovy)

Comment: @wooki Is `given` an alias for `setup`? I wanted to use `setup` before a `given` and was rejected

Comment: @FedericoPiazza yes, it is. Hence one would either use a `setup` or `given` but not both at the same time, the additional grouping can be achieved through `and` label.